# Where can I host expo project so that my team could access it through expo app

Tags: react-native, expo

When I run `expo start`, it start the app in my local machine and gives me URL to access it through expo app on the device, since URL is local, my team member from another country can not access it, and I do not want to open ports on my local machine, is there any hosts where I could host the app so that my team members could access it through expo app in their devices?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run this command in your project:

`expo publish`

From there you can go to your expo dashboard on [expo.io](https://expo.io) 
and share the link of your app to anyone you want.

Comment: That was in front of me all the time! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

No need to publish.

Here is how is done in 2022.

"While you’re developing your project, you’re writing code on your computer, and when you use Expo CLI, a server and the Metro bundler run on your machine and bundle up all your source code and make it available from a URL. " (expo decs: https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/publishing/)

In 2022, you would just need to install a module with

```
yarn add @expo/ngrok@^4.1.0
```

after installation run the following command in the terminal to start your dev server from a tunnel URL:

```
npx expo start --tunnel
```

Lastly, scan the QR code generated or follow the link generated right underneath the QR code. It should look like this:

```
› Metro waiting on exp://l3jdh6s.anonymous.19000.exp.direct:80
```

(with the condition that they download the "Expo Go" app, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

From February 12, 2024 the `expo publish` will stop working.

The new way is to use EAS and use the `eas update` command. This will give you a link that hosts your app. You will be able to open the app through Expo Go or a development version.

See Expo [blog post](https://blog.expo.dev/eas-update-is-now-generally-available-6532d25e750).